# Messages on macOS keeps "forgetting" all my messages

Tags: messages, monterey

Every time I open Messages on my macOS 12.6.1 MacPro2013, there are no threads visible on the left. New messages appear, but older ones do not. It seems to have "forgotten" everything. If I close and re-open, the new ones I had a moment ago are also gone.

Any ideas where to start? This was not happening in the past.

Comment: The Message database lives in `~/Library/Messages/` although the structure itself is pretty impenetrable. Maybe try dragging the entire content out to somewhere safe & testing again [this won't fix your past messages, of course, but it may indicate corruption somewhere.]